# My ethernet interface name has changed from eth0 to eth1

Tags: networking, udev, interface

I was doing some work in GNS3 in which I had to run a Virtual machine(tiny version of OS) and needed to connect that machine to a virtual router that was running also on GNS3. For this I needed to set an ip address in one of my interfaces(`eth0`).

After I close GNS3, and failed to get internet from port. I also found that my Ethernet interface name has changed from `eth0` to `eth1`.

I think that is the reason I am not getting internet form my LAN port.

I deleted that project in GNS3 but problem persists.

Is there any way to change it again to `eth0` ?

Comment: Whats the output of `grep '<MAC_Address>' /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` ? ..replace `<MAC_Address>` with MAC address of the interface..

Comment: @heemayl , th o/p is 

`SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="68:f7:28:23:ce:30", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"`

Comment: What is GNS3?..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to modify the `udev` rule for the network interface to change the name. As seen in the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*",
ATTR{address}=="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1",
KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
```

the name has been changed to `eth1`.

To change the name of the interface back to `eth0`:

- Open the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` with your favorite editor
- Find the rule matching your MAC address
- Change the `NAME` value from `eth1` to `eth0` i.e. `NAME="eth0"`
- To apply changes without restarting run `sudo udevadm trigger`

Comment: last command showing like this : `control: unrecognized option '--related-rules'`

Comment: @Deb try `sudo udevadm trigger`

Comment: ok, interface name has changed. but still not getting internet. ethernet port showing connected but no internet.

Comment: @Deb How did you configure the network interface?

Comment: I did the configuaration in GNS3 by adding the tiny OS.image file.

Comment: @Deb There could be many reasons to that i think..in my opinion as the current issue is resolved you should ask it as  a different question..

Comment: I asked a different question to the same problem, you like to answer it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/638394/why-does-my-eth0-interface-always-shows-the-same-inet-addr-in-different-lan

Comment: Your example has `NAME=="eth1"'` with a single tick at the very end.  I am not convinced that ought to be there because I can't find its pair.  Is that a typo or should it be there?

Answer (score 1):

first, SU -l into root then perform the following:

cd /etc/sysconfig

ls

cd network-scripts/

ls

vi ifcfg-eth0

VI is an editor that is very dangerous lol, but be careful to not change anything unless that is the objective.

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu 16.04 and above you should not use `KERNEL=="eth*"`. So you should just use

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*",
ATTR{address}=="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", NAME="eth1"
```